# Foreign key to the same table

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I'm trying users can comment publications. I've created the table *Comments* with EF Core.

There are multiple levels of comments and I've implmeneted the following way:

Table **Publications**

```
- Id (primary key)
```

Table **Comments**

```
- PublicationId (foreing key to Publication)
- Comment
- ParentComment (foreign key to Comments, that is, the same table)
```

The problem is an error warn me I can't créate a foreing key to the same table. How can I implement the hierarchy then?

Comment: Can you share your entity model?

Comment: Are you using code first ?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is suppose to look something like this

```
public int Id {get; set;}
public virtual Publication Publication {get; set;} // If Publication is an object
public virtual Comment Comment {get; set;}
public virtual Comment ParentComment {get; set;}
```

Comment: One comment I have is that if you give the property the same name as the type you'll most likely run into clashes during compilation.

Comment: @Paul That's not true. Property names can be given the same name as the type. It'll compile fine.

Comment: My bad, my mind went to nested classes. If you have a property in a class that is: **Comment Comment {get; set;}** and the Comment class is a nested class in the same class as the property, then you will get that issue.

Comment: It's similar but Comment it's just a string, the problem cames when I try to insert a new comment on a Publication: "The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY SAME TABLE constraint \"FK_Comments_Comments_ParentCommentId\"